# appengine spring aop java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.sun.reflect")

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, google-app-engine

I am creating application with spring aspect but in app engine when I hit first request then exception occurs while initialize spring framework.

Exception stack trace is as below:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adminController' defined in file [PATH\PACKAGE\AdminController.class]: 
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: 
Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is java.security.AccessControlException: 
access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.sun.reflect")
```

My Aspect

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class AuthorizationAspect {

    @Around(value="@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
    public Object interceptApplicationRequest(
            ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("test");
        return proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

My Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/admin")
public class AdminController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView add(){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("add");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

Configuration in XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.package.name" />

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

Is AOP not allowed in app engine framework?

App Engine version: 1.9.7
Spring Framework: 4.0.3

Comment: You might need to show more than just the exception in order for anyone to really help.  What's the code look like for the controller, and what's the relevant XML configuration look like?

Comment: Added code and relevant XML configuration.

Comment: I don't think GAE will have a problem with it unless it's trying to do File IO or something.  Does this have problems running locally or just when deployed to production?

Comment: @jmort253 This problem occurs in locally as well as in production.

Comment: The full stack trace would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the exception message, it is likely that the library you are using relies on some classes that are not in the App Engine's White list: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist

In particular, I don't see any of sun.reflect* classes in this white list. Hence, you are getting AccessControllException.

Comment: But as per my understanding Spring Aspect did not required any reflection to system classes.